# Use substitution to delete everything up to a point on a line

Tags: vim, text-formatting, vi, editors, line-editor

I want to use a global substitution in Vim to delete everything *up to* `https`.

## Before

```
The website is https://website.com
The website is https://website.com
The website is https://website.com
```

## After

```
https://website.com
https://website.com
https://website.com
```

Comment: You might want to check out https://vi.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Many ways to skin a cat. Substitute is most appropriate here but you could also use following global command: `:g/http/norm dn` or even `:g/ht/norm dn`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:%s/.*\(https:\)/\1/
```

`:` gets you into `ex` mode.

`%` is a quick way of saying `1,$`, which means for line number 1 to the end

`s/` is `substitute` using `/` as a delimiter.

`.*\(https:\)` is anything followed by `https:`, remembering the https:

`\1` is the remembered text.

Comment: You just taught me how capturing groups work in substitutions. Great answer!

Comment: @icarus How to remove everything up to the first occurrence of a word in each line. I tried your suggestion, but the command matches till last occurrence of word in each line.

Comment: The "global" command suggested by @Ingo Karkat works as I want!

Comment: @mvsagar Glad you found an answer that works for you. I think the "global" command has a problem if the pattern matches the first thing on the line. In effect the "global" command first finds the lines to work on, then for each line found it executes the command(s). It is already at the first pattern, so the "n" part of the "dn" gets you to the next instance, and then the '"d" part deletes it. Using `:%s/.\{-\}\(https:\)/\1/` should give the correct result even at the start of the line. See `:help non-greedy`. Note this doesn't work in classic vi.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the best approach, but it works.

```
:%s/^.*https/https/g
```

Replaces everything from start of line until `https` with `https`.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers so far show a generic substitution with a regular expression that either captures or duplicates the `https` prefix. However, since you're asking about Vim, you can avoid these by ending the match early via the nifty [`\ze`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cze) atom:

```
:%s/.*\zehttps://
```

This `:substitute`s in all lines (`:%`) everything (`.*`) from the start of a line until (the last (!) match of) `https:` (use non-greedy matching (`.\{-}`) if there can be multiple occurrences in a line), but ending the match just before that (`\ze`), replacing it with nothing (`//`).

#### short clever alternative

Already mentioned in the comments, `:global` locates all the lines with a URL, handily sets the search pattern, and then deletes from the cursor position to the first match (`dn`):

```
:global/http/normal! dn
```

#### obscure alternative

```
0d/https<CR>qqqqqjdn@qq@q
```

Deletes the current line's match manually (`0d/https<CR>`), then clears register `q` (`qqq`) and starts recording a *recursive macro* (`qq`) that goes to the next line (`j`), deletes until the match (`dn`), primes the recursion (`@q`), ends recording (`q`), and finally triggers the macro (`@q`) so that it runs until there are no more matches.

Comment: You actually need `\ze` here, not `\zs`. This ends up doing the opposite, stripping the `https` part. But yeah, this is much better than the other regexes, it's what I had in mind.

Comment: I actually also think the regex solution could be improved by using a delimiter other than `/`, since here `//` is not part of the match but it *happens to be* what follows `https:` in the text... Using a different delimiter would prevent that initial confusion about what those are.

Comment: @filbranden you're right; corrected. Great that you've noticed!

Comment: @Ingo, the 'global' command works exactly as I wanted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, since URLs never have literal space characters in them, you could apply a substitution to each line that deletes everything up to and including the last space:

```
:% s/.* //
```